# retrieve data from NSUserDefaults to TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I save values of two labels through NSUserDefaults                     :

```
- (IBAction) saveData
{
    // Store the data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:autore.text forKey:@"Author"];
    [defaults setObject:testo.text forKey:@"Text"];
    [defaults synchronize];    
}
```

Then i try tot retrieve those values in a tableView                     :

```
// NSArray
@synthesize dataArray;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[prefs objectForKey:@"Author"], [prefs objectForKey:@"Text"],nil];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// There is only one section.
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of time zone names.
return [dataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ..............
 ..............

 NSString *string = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 // Authors
 cell.textLabel.text = string;
 // Text
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = string;

 return cell;
}
```

I would obtain result as like picture:
[image: figure]

Comment: The way I see you doing this you only can ever have one author and one text. Do you intend on having multiple authors and texts?

Comment: yes, having multiple authors/text

Comment: Well then you need to create a subclass with two properties, e.g. author and text. And then make an array of those objects. Then you can say `cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].author;` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].text;`

Comment: Also, were you planning on storing these all in the user defaults?  If so, maybe you should look into CoreData instead. It will easily do a lot of this for you.

Comment: pratically i would save favourite author/text for the user. i don't know if nsuserdefault i the best way, maybe i must use sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, but first of all I need to know what you are saving. Are U saving just one string to the defaults or more, because if you are saving more I would recommend to add all this files first of all to array and then save it to the defaults.

So
 `NSMutableArray * myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [myArray addObject:myfirstauthor];
    [myArray addObject:mysecondauthor];
    [myArray addObject:mythirdauthor]; ....`

the same with quotations....

and then i would save arrays to the NSUserDefaults as you correctly did. On loading for the next time, take these arrays from defaults and retrieve information from there.

Because in this case U're saving just one long string.

One more notice, but I am not sure about this, maybe everything saved to the defaults should be type of NSDATA, but i am not sure, take a look on programming guide.=)

Happy coding=)

Comment: Thk for the reply. I save multiple pair value author/text in the NSUserDefault but i don't know how retrieve to the tableViev (like my picture).

Comment: ok and autore.txt is what??? Is it UITextView or something different?Because I don't know what exactly do you want to store? You want to store all authors or only one favorite???=)